# Passing Term-Document Matrix to Gensim LDA Model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, nlp, gensim

My term-document matrix is in a numpy matrix format, and I have a dictionary to represent the  of the term-document matrix.

Is there any way I can easily pass these two into Gensim's LDA model?

```
tdMatrix = np.load('tdmatrix.npy')
dictionary = cPickle.load(open('dictionary.p', 'r')) # stores term represented by each column
```

Can I pass this somewhow to gensim.models.ldamodel.LDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Gensim uses pretty much the same structure to represent a bag of words corpus, but I don't think a default dictionary or numpy array would be compatible.
Gensim's API lists a few "corpusreaders" that can accommodate various formats, but those seem to be built for importing data from other tool kits.
So maybe in your case the easiest solution would be to reconstruct the documents using your matrix and dictionary as a list of separated strings. Then convert your list to Gensim's bag of word corpus and finally to LDA as shown in the [tutorials](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#corpus-streaming-one-document-at-a-time).

This approach has the added benefit that you can apply Gensim's preprocessing functions and filter words with low/high frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

To treat a 2D `numpy` (or even `scipy.sparse.csc`) array as a gensim corpus, use the built-in [matutils.Scipy2Corpus](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html#gensim.matutils.Scipy2Corpus) function.

Comment: is there any documentation about exactly the format expected? For example, I have a sparse csc matrix saved to disk that is about 18 GB. The columns are different terms, the rows are documents with non-zero counts for the given term. The "*2Corpus" functions describe accepting csc, but it's not clear if the documents need to be the column dimension or if the terms should be the column dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Given a numpy with with the document vectors in each row just use:

```
corpus = gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(array)
```