# Trying to make use of a library to conduct some topic modeling, but it's not going well

Tags: python, gensim, lda, corpus

I have a .csv term-document matrix, and I wanna perform some latent dirichlet allocation using gensim in python. However, I'm not particularly familiar with Python *or* LDA.

I posted in the gensim...forum? I dunno if that's what it's called. The guy that wrote the package responded and had this to say:

> how big is your term-document CSV matrix?
>
> If it's small enough = fits in RAM, you could:
>
> 1) use numpy.loadtxt()
>   to load your CSV into an in-memory matrix
>
> 2) convert the matrix to a corpus with gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus() . Check out its documents_columns flag, it lets you switch between document-term and term-document transposition easily.
>
> 3) use that corpus to train your LDA model.

So that leads me to believe that the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220927/passing-term-document-matrix-to-gensim-lda-model) isn't correct.

It seems like a dictionary is a necessary input to a LDA model; is this not correct? Here's what I have that I think successfully sticks the .csv into a corpus.

```
file = np.genfromtxt(fname=fPathName, dtype="int", delimiter=",", skip_header=True, missing_values="", filling_values=0)


corpus = gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(file, documents_columns=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: turns out that a Gensim dictionary and a Python dictionary are not exactly the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from Gensim documentation I took this snip of code:

```
from gensim.models import LdaModel
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

# Create a corpus from a list of texts
common_dictionary = Dictionary(common_texts)
common_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in common_texts]

# Train the model on the corpus.
lda = LdaModel(common_corpus, num_topics=10)
```

The file you want to analyse is a csv so to open it you can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename) # add header=None if the file has no column names
```

Once you import the file you have everything loaded into a data frame, you need to combine all text into a unique list (see first comment of gensim code snip) that should look like this

```
["text one..", "text 2..", "text 3..."]
```

You can do that by iterating through the data frame and iteratevely adding text to an empty list. Before to do that you also need to check which column of your csv file contain the text to analyse.

```
common_texts = [] # initialise empty list
for ind, row in df.iteritem():
    text = row[name_column_with_text]
    common_texts.append(text)
```

Once you get your list of text you can simply apply the code from gensim documentation.
Of course you might get memory problems, it depends on the size of your csv file.